# Define what method to call based on value of Optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination, optional-chaining

Is it possible, to somehow alter the code below, so in case of no `status` value provided to return all the PaymentLog objects stored in the database instead of only the ones with `status` equal with `404`? Basically, I would like if the `status` variable has not been provided to call another method in the service layer `logService.getAllPaymentLogs()`

```
@GetMapping(Endpoints.LOGS.PAYMENT_LOGS)
public Page<PaymentLog> getPaymentLog(@RequestParam Optional<Integer> status) {
    return logService.getPaymentLogStatus(status.orElse(404), PageRequest.of(0, 10));
}
```

These are the `getPaymentLogStatus()` and `getAllPaymentLogs`

```
@Override
public Page<PaymentLog> getPaymentLog(Pageable pageable) {
    return paymentLogRepository.getAllBy(pageable);
}
```

And

```
@Override
public Page<PaymentLog> getPaymentLog(int status, Pageable pageable) {
    return paymentLogRepository.getAllByStatus(status, pageable);
}
```

Comment: does your `paymentLogRepository` have a method like `getAll()`?

Comment: `status.map(s -> getPaymentLog(s, page)).orElseGet(() ->  getPaymentLog(page))`?

Comment: Thank you. "s" is the value of  "status", I assume.

Comment: @Dc235 Yeah, call it whatever you want in the lambda, it's just the element inside the Optional

Answer (score 1):

@123 answered the question in the commenting session:

```
status.map(s -> getPaymentLog(s, page)).orElseGet(() -> getPaymentLog(page))
```